# spring boot + mongodb + camel route connection issue

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am new to camel route, trying to create a route which will read the content of a file and insert in mongodb, there is some wrong with it, seems like connection endpoint is not correct.

**Route Class**

```
@Component
public class EmailResponseRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:C:/EmailResponseAutomation/response/")
        .to("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017?database=email_response&collection=emailResponse&operation=save");
    }
}
```

**Log Error**

> org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootInitializationException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route
>   route1 at: >>>
>   To[mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017?database=email_response&collection=emailResponse&operation=save]
>   <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[file:C:/workspace/EmailRes...
>   because of Failed to resolve endpoint:
>   mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017?collection=emailResponse&database=email_response&operation=save
>   due to: No component found with scheme: mongodb   at
>   org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:126)
>   ~[camel-spring-boot-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]    at
>   org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:41)
>   ~[camel-spring-boot-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]    at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:399)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:353)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:887)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   com.era.conf.ApplicationConfiguration.main(ApplicationConfiguration.java:12)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route
>   route1 at: >>>
>   To[mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017?database=email_response&collection=emailResponse&operation=save]
>   <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[file:C:/workspace/EmailRes...
>   because of Failed to resolve endpoint:
>   mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017?collection=emailResponse&database=email_response&operation=save
>   due to: No component found with scheme: mongodb   at
>   org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootApplicationController.run(CamelSpringBootApplicationController.java:73)
>   ~[camel-spring-boot-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]    at
>   org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelMainRunController$DaemonTask.run(CamelMainRunController.java:43)
>   ~[camel-spring-boot-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_102]     at
>   org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelMainRunController.start(CamelMainRunController.java:36)
>   ~[camel-spring-boot-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]    at
>   org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:113)
>   ~[camel-spring-boot-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]    ... 16 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to
>   create route route1 at: >>>
>   To[mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017?database=email_response&collection=emailResponse&operation=save]
>   <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[file:C:/workspace/EmailRes...
>   because of Failed to resolve endpoint:
>   mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017?collection=emailResponse&database=email_response&operation=save
>   due to: No component found with scheme: mongodb   at
>   org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1072)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:196)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:974)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:3295)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3018)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:175)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2848)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2844)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2867)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2844)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2813)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.main.Main.doStart(Main.java:127)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:138)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootApplicationController.run(CamelSpringBootApplicationController.java:68)
>   ~[camel-spring-boot-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]    ... 20 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to
>   resolve endpoint:
>   mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017?collection=emailResponse&database=email_response&operation=save
>   due to: No component found with scheme: mongodb   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:594)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:79)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:211)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:107)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:113)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.resolveEndpoint(SendDefinition.java:62)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.createProcessor(SendDefinition.java:56)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessorImpl(ProcessorDefinition.java:534)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:495)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:219)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1069)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   ... 35 common frames omitted

Answer (score 1):

You need to have apache camel mongodb dependency. Add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>x.y.z</version>
    <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
</dependency>
```

As you can see it from the exception

> No component found with scheme: mongodb

Comment: When you use Spring Boot its a good idea to use the `-starter` dependency, eg `camel-mongodb-starter` then it has spring boot auto configuration and other goodies included.

Comment: @ClausIbsen, Yup Agreed