# Camel route creation error, No component found with scheme: mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am new to Apache camel, trying to write a route which should read data from a file on specified path and store the content in mongodb.
Seems like I am doing something wrong while specifying the mongodb path, as a result I am getting error on console (`Failed to create route route1 at: >>> To[mongodb:myDb?database=email_response&collection=emailResponse&operation=save] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[file:C://workspace//Emai... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: mongodb://myDb?collection=emailResponse&database=email_response&operation=save due to: No component found with scheme: mongodb`), please have a look.

**Console Output**

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
>   re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 2018-03-19 12:02:43.234
>   ERROR 4616 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication
>   : Application run failed
>
> org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootInitializationException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route
>   route1 at: >>>
>   To[mongodb:myDb?database=email_response&collection=emailResponse&operation=save]
>   <<< in route:
>   Route(route1)[[From[file:C://workspace//Emai...
>   because of Failed to resolve endpoint:
>   mongodb://myDb?collection=emailResponse&database=email_response&operation=save
>   due to: No component found with scheme: mongodb   at
>   org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:126)
>   ~[camel-spring-boot-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]    at
>   org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:41)
>   ~[camel-spring-boot-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]    at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:399)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:353)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:887)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]     at
>   com.era.conf.ApplicationConfiguration.main(ApplicationConfiguration.java:12)
>   [classes/:na] Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route
>   route1 at: >>>
>   To[mongodb:myDb?database=email_response&collection=emailResponse&operation=save]
>   <<< in route:
>   Route(route1)[[From[file:C://workspace//Emai...
>   because of Failed to resolve endpoint:
>   mongodb://myDb?collection=emailResponse&database=email_response&operation=save
>   due to: No component found with scheme: mongodb   at
>   org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootApplicationController.run(CamelSpringBootApplicationController.java:73)
>   ~[camel-spring-boot-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]    at
>   org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelMainRunController$DaemonTask.run(CamelMainRunController.java:43)
>   ~[camel-spring-boot-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_102]     at
>   org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelMainRunController.start(CamelMainRunController.java:36)
>   ~[camel-spring-boot-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]    at
>   org.apache.camel.spring.boot.RoutesCollector.onApplicationEvent(RoutesCollector.java:113)
>   ~[camel-spring-boot-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]    ... 16 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to
>   create route route1 at: >>>
>   To[mongodb:myDb?database=email_response&collection=emailResponse&operation=save]
>   <<< in route:
>   Route(route1)[[From[file://workspace//Emai...
>   because of Failed to resolve endpoint:
>   mongodb://myDb?collection=emailResponse&database=email_response&operation=save
>   due to: No component found with scheme: mongodb   at
>   org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1072)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:196)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:974)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:3295)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:3018)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:175)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2848)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2844)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2867)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2844)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2813)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.main.Main.doStart(Main.java:127)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:138)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootApplicationController.run(CamelSpringBootApplicationController.java:68)
>   ~[camel-spring-boot-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]    ... 20 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to
>   resolve endpoint:
>   mongodb://myDb?collection=emailResponse&database=email_response&operation=save
>   due to: No component found with scheme: mongodb   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:594)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:79)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:211)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:107)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:113)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.resolveEndpoint(SendDefinition.java:62)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.createProcessor(SendDefinition.java:56)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessorImpl(ProcessorDefinition.java:534)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:495)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:219)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   at
>   org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1069)
>   ~[camel-core-2.17.0.jar:2.17.0]   ... 35 common frames omitted

**Camel Route**

```
@Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:C://workspace//EmailResponseAutomation//response//")
        .to("mongodb:myDb?database=email_response&collection=emailResponse&operation=save");
    }
```

**Dependencies**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Camel -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring boot + mongodb + camel route connection issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49321201/spring-boot-mongodb-camel-route-connection-issue)

Comment: Don't ask the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use Camel with MongoDB you need the [Camel MongoDB Component](http://camel.apache.org/mongodb.html), add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to your pom.

Comment: I added this dependency, now I have a new exception `org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootInitializationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> To[mongodb:myDb?database=email_response&collection=emailResponse&operation=save] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[file:C://workspace//Emai... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: mongodb://myDb?collection=emailResponse&database=email_response&operation=save due to: No bean could be found in the registry for: myDb of type: com.mongodb.Mongo`

Comment: I added `@Bean
 public Mongo myDb(){
  return new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27017));
 }` bean,now Camel route is running, but data is not injecting in mongodb. I am getting a new exception `org.apache.camel.component.mongodb.CamelMongoDbException: org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: com.mongodb.DBObject but has value: GenericFile[C:\workspace\EmailResponseAutomation\response\SampleEmailResponseFile.txt]`

Comment: @ShamimAhmad Your question is answered, please accept the answer. If you have other problems, ask another question, don't use comments for this.